# Can't install Laravel from my source vendor/autoload.php is not generated for some reason

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to create another environment of my project so i decided to do it via source control and not just copy paste of the source files.

So what i did is `git clone...`
cd to the app folder
run `composer install`

the install threw an exception: 

`[RuntimeException]
  Could not scan for classes inside "vendor/autoload.php" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder`

As far as I know, this `vendor/autoload.php` file supposed to be generated by the `composer install` command. composer update or -no-scripts gave the same result...

this is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "torann/geoip": "0.2.*@dev"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database",
            "app/Facades",
            "app/Services",
            "vendor/autoload.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `"vendor/autoload.php"` from autoload>classmap

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Facades",
        "app/Services",
        "vendor/autoload.php"
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an almost similar issue on my linux machine, mine was:

> "Could not scan for classes inside `app/facades` which does not appear
>   to be a file nor a folder"

I solved it by editing my `composer.json`. I changed  `app/facades` to `app/Facades` in the classmap below:

```
"classmap": [
    "database/seeds",
    "database/factories",
    "app/Facades"
]
```

Apparently composer was case sensitive, my facade folder is : Facades not facades